# find all references/ involved classes, enum used in a method

Tags: java, eclipse, flex4

I have to document the involved classes, enums and nested method calls (references) used in a method call.

For example, I have to document all the methods and references used when user clicks a retrieve button in UI.

I am using Eclipse Kepler. Right now, I just read the code line-by-line manually which is time-consuming as the application is complicated.

Is there any faster way or plugin that suit my need?

P.S. I am not finding the callers of a method (ctrl+shift+g doesn't suit my need), but what a method calls and uses. For example,

```
import status.Status;
import biz.B;

public class A {

    public String testA()
    {
        B b= new B();
        return b.getB()+ " "+Status.Active ;
    }
}
```

For method **testA()**, I have to record **status.Status** and **biz.B**.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Find usages will get use usages across project - Ctrl+G

Comment: I have edited my question and added an example. Please help :)